Is it possible to resize an xarray adaptor of a vector?
After seeing the example of xtensor matrix adaptors of 1D containers, I was wondering if it is also possible to have a resizeable adaptor of STL containers like vectors.
In the process, I would like to also find out and use the type of such an adaptor, instead of using auto.
Starting with the C-style array adaptor and compute() function --which multiplies the 2x1 row vector with a 2x1 column and returns the xarray as a 2x2 matrix-- I got as far as
#include <cstddef>
#include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xadapt.hpp>

template <class A>
void compute ( A& a ) {
    xt::xarray<double> b {1., 2.};
    b.reshape({2, 1});
    a = a * b; // size has changed, shape is now { 2, 2 }
}

int main() {
    std::size_t size = 2;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    double* datavx = new double [ size ];
    
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        datavx [ i ] = i;
    
    std::vector<std::size_t>   shapevx = { size };
    std::vector<std::size_t> stridesvx = { 1 };
    
    auto vx = xt::adapt ( datavx, size, xt::acquire_ownership(), shapevx, stridesvx );
    
    std::cout << "\nbefore reshape\n";
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        std::cout << datavx [ i ] << " ";
    compute ( vx );
    std::cout << "\nafter reshape\n";
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < size * size; i++ )
        std::cout << datavx [ i ] << " ";

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::vector<double> datav (size);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
        datav[i] = i;

    std::vector<std::size_t> shapev = shapevx;
    std::vector<std::size_t> stridesv = stridesvx;

    using shape_type = std::vector<size_t>;
    using adaptor_typev = xt::xarray_adaptor<xt::xbuffer_adaptor<double*, xt::acquire_ownership>, xt::layout_type::dynamic, shape_type >;
    adaptor_typev my_adaptorv = xt::adapt(datav.data(), size, xt::acquire_ownership(), shapev, stridesv);
    std::cout << "\n";
    
    std::cout << "\nbefore reshape\n";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << datav[i] << " ";
    compute(my_adaptorv);
    std::cout << "\nafter reshape\n";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < size * size; i++)
        std::cout << datav[i] << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
    // prints 0 1 0 2

}

The output that I get from the C-style xarray_adaptor (from the xtensor website) and the std:vector xarray_adaptor, respectively, is:
before reshape
0 1
after reshape
0 1 0 2

before reshape
0 1
after reshape
0 1 nan -5.11336e-311

==== Program exited with exit code: 3221226356 ====
Time elapsed: 000:00.016 (MM:SS.MS)

The last two values suggest that the resize has not happened, and the non-zero exit code shows all is not well. If I run it in the debugger, it exits with a SIGTRAP at the end of main(). The top of the call stack says ntdll!RtllsZeroMemory.
Does that mean that to resize an xarray adaptor of an std::vector, I need to resize the vector separately? Or is there a way to do it without trying to become owner of the vector's data (that does not sound right to begin with)?

xt::adapt(vdata.data(), vsize, xt::acquire_ownership(), ...) will eventually lead to undefined behavior by way of double destruction. You tell the adapter it now owns the data and needs to delete it, but the vector vdata also believes it owns the data, and will also delete it.

In the second loop, vdata[i] exibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. vdata.size() is still 2, valid indexes are 0 and 1.

Show a [mcve] that actually reproduces the output shown. You are talking about "the std:vector xarray_adaptor", but none such appears in your code.

Your [mre] is missing a definition of the compute() function (it is not part of the xtensor library). Code in questions must be self-contained, not relying on external links (not to mention that there are three compute() functions in that link, making us do manual overload resolution).

"Starting with the C-style array adaptor" -- Why? If you follow your own link, then scroll up (same page), there is "Adapting std::vector". Why would you not start with "Adapting std::vector" when your goal is to adapt std::vector?

Sorry @IgorTandetnik, example is now a full program. So the double delete (one from the adaptor and one from the vector) are what makes the program crash? The other point you make, about the resize() not happening, is that because the ownership of the vector does not change?

Thanks @JaMiT - the "Adapting std::vector" code is by far the easiest but the 2 things I mention in my post, using a specified type rather than author, and resizing the container after adapting, are not in that example.

Like I said, you are using the adaptor for C-style arrays to adapt the raw data managed by the vector. And you tell that adaptor to take ownership of the data, all while the vector also owns that same data. The vector has no idea you are pulling its data right from under its feet.  The part of the code that deals with datav and my_adaptorv has undefined behavior galore. See whether the outcome changes if you do auto my_adaptorv = xt::adapt(datav, shapev, stridesv);

The comments by @JaMit and @IgorTandetnik helped me in the right direction -- I did need an adaptor of a vector not a C-style array.
But the examples with vector adaptors all used auto declarations and I still wanted to know the type of the adaptor.
An old answer on StackOverflow allowed me to combine the two: this bit of code shows the type of the adaptor, which I then used to do the declaration 'manually'.
